# hex string to Integer parsing exception handling in java

Tags: java, string, parsing, exception, integer

I need to parse string hex value to the Integer value. Like this:

```
String hex = "2A"; //The answer is 42  
int intValue = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
```

But when I insert an incorrect hex value (for example "LL") then I get `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "LL"` How I can avoid it (for example return 0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just catch the exception and set the default value. However, you need to declare the variable outside the `try` block.

```
int intValue;
try {
    intValue = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    intValue = 0;
}
```

If you need to set the value using an initializer expression (say, for a `final` variable), you'll have to package up the logic in a method:

```
public int parseHex(String hex) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return 0;
    }
}

// elsewhere...
final int intValue = parseHex(hex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose it in a try catch block. That is how [Exception Handling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) works: -

```
int intValue = 0;
try {
    intValue = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Hex Value");
    // intValue will contain 0 only from the default value assignment.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> For input string: "LL" How I can avoid it (for example return 0)?

Just catch the exception and assign **zero** to **intvalue**

```
int intValue;
try {
String hex = "2A"; //The answer is 42  
intValue = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex){
  System.out.println("Wrong Input"); // just to be more expressive
 invalue=0;
}
```

Comment: Note that you have to declare your variable `intValue` outside the try block. Scope matters.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* catch the exception and return zero instead.

```
public static int parseHexInt(String hex) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

However, I recommend re-evaluating your approach, as 0 is a valid hex number as well, and doesn't signify invalid input such as `"LL"`.

Answer (score 0):

> How I can avoid it (for example return 0)

Using a simple method which will `return 0` in case a `NumberFormatException` occurrs

```
public int getHexValue(String hex){

    int result = 0;

    try {
        result = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
     } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```